# Date Conversion in javascript to (d MMMMM yyyy HH:mm am) without momentjs

Tags: javascript, angular

I have date in this format "2020-02-07T16:13:38.22" i want to convert this to " d MMMMM yyyy HH:mm a " to this format without using the momentjs.

below method is used to convert the date

```js
const options = {
  day: "numeric",
  month: "long",
  year: "numeric",


}

var date1 = new Date("2020-02-07T16:13:38.22").toLocaleDateString("en-US", options);
const options1 = {
  hour12: true,
  hour: "numeric",
  minute: "2-digit",

}

var date2 = new Date("2020-02-07T16:13:38.22").toLocaleTimeString("en-US", options1);
var res = date1 + ', ' + date2;



console.log(res)
```

Above code gives the result "February 7, 2020, 4:13 PM" but i need "7 February 2020 4:13 PM" i.e date first then month and year and time and the code which i tried is longer please help me in the required result.

Comment: Extract year, month, etc. with getFullYear(), getMonth(), etc. and then assemble in a string?

Comment: Why do this without moment? Date handling libraries are exactly there to help you produce custom formatted dates. Sure, you can also do it without using one, assuming you know what you're doing but it *always helps* to not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Probably easier to Create an enum of Months and build it yourself by using the javascript date functions

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date

Answer (score 1):

In Angular I find it easiest to inject the date pipe for complex date formatting

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  providers: [    
    DatePipe
  ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  constructor(private datePipe: DatePipe) {
  }

  formatted: string;  

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const d = new Date();
    this.formatted = this.datePipe.transform(d, 'd MMMM yyyy h:mm a');
  }
}
```

Working example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t72srm)

NB, I would normally format this in the html, but it looked like you were asking for a typescript solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the *date* pipe :

```
{{'2020-02-07T16:13:38.22' | date:'d LLLL yyyy h:mm a'}}
```

More details of the *date formats* can be found in the [`Date Pipe Angular docs`](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe).

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this, but you would need to convert the hours to a 12 hour versus 24 hour format.  Or if it it is being used in HTML use an angular pipe as stated above.

```
const event = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));
const months =  ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

var test =  event.getDate()  + ' ' + months[event.getMonth()] + ' ' + event.getFullYear() + ' ' + event.getHours() + ':' + event.getMinutes()

console.log(test)
```